# Is it possible to redirect a url (using IP) to another url (other IP)?

Tags: ssh, browser, webserver, portforwarding

I want to access 2 webservices in a remote/private network from my local/private network:

```
remote webservice 1 (RWS1): 192.168.0.2:8083
remote webservice 2 (RWS2): 192.168.0.1:80
remote ssh client  (RSC)  : 192.168.0.2
local ssh server   (LSS)  : my.server.com (local: 192.168.1.1)
local webserver 1  (LWS1) : 192.168.0.1:80
```

**access RWS1** (this is working)
ssh-client connects to ssh-server incl. port-forwarding:

```
RSC: ssh -R0.0.0.0:8080:192.168.0.2:8083 user@my.server.com
```

enable all local IPs to access port at "LSS": 192.168.1.1:8080:

```
LSS: socat TCP-LISTEN:8083,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:8080
```

now I am able to access "http://192.168.1.1:8083/" and what I get is the result of RWS1. As this web-application uses relative redirects, this is working perfectly!

**access RWS2** (this is **NOT** working)
ssh-client connects to ssh-server incl. port-forwarding:

```
RSC: ssh -R0.0.0.0:8080:192.168.0.1:80 user@my.server.com
```

enable all local IPs to access port at "LSS": 192.168.1.1:8080:

```
LSS: sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:8080
```

now I am able to access "http://192.168.1.1/" and what I get is the result of RWS2 - but as this web-application uses **absolute redirects to 192.168.0.1**, I am immediately redirected to my local LWS1 (e.g. my browser accesses "http://192.168.1.1/", but RWS2 answers with a redirect to "http://192.168.0.1/html/index.html").

=> how to force my browser to map everything pointing to 192.168.0.1 to go to 192.168.1.1 ?

(the good thing is, that I do not have to deal with certificates, as connection is done via http :-) )

thanks
michael

Comment: Solved this by assigning the LWS1 the same IP as my LSS - I see this as a workaround for this specific case, but not as a generic solution.